# Side loading APPX Bundle don't work in windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have a windows universal app that when deployed to the store works on all devices.

When I create a appx bundle for side loading, it works on all devices except in windows 10 mobile, it installs the app but it does not open it, or opens and crashes eventually?

Obs: When checking the diference bewteen the appx bundle from the store (way smaller) from the one in my side loading, the bundle from the store does not have the dependencies folders that the one from the side-loading as!

Anyone??

Comment: Which appx file doesn't work - the one from the store, or your one that you submitted to the store?

Comment: the one from the store works the one I created to the store  also works! the one I create for side loading does not work!

Comment: What did you do differently for the side-loading appx vs. the store appx?

Comment: Ok! this was solved it was a bug and fixed!